# Using foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop, foreach

I break the code of the **for** loop without using **break** like I have for loop given below.And when **i** is 1 or 2 or 3 or any else but if condition is true then loop will be terminated because **i** will be 5 if the condition is true.And so **NO** need of break is needed there.Beacause I do not want to use **break**.I have done like this here.It works.

```
int myCondition=0;
bool flag=false;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   if(myCondition==0)
   {
       flag=true;
   }
   if(flag)
       i=5;
}
```

But now I want to use **foreach loop** and in this loop when some condition is true then I want to break the **foreach loop** code.So what should I do here for breaking the **foreach loop** code without using **break** ? Like in the above for loop I have initialize **i** to 5 when condition is true.In the **foreach loop** anything like that to do to avoid **break**.

Comment: Why not use `break`?  That's what it's there for...

Comment: @Nick Craver.. Is it ok to use break in our code ?

Comment: @Harikrishna - Absolutely, it's a fundamental feature of the language.  I think `goto` is what you're thinking of, and traditionally yes you should steer clear of that (for readability mainly)

Comment: Of course it's OK. It's wrong NOT to use it. Unless you can give me a good reason why not?

Comment: Is it ok to use goto in our code then?

Comment: @Harikrisha: For an answer to your last comment, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: @Harikrisha: there are some concerns around `break` and `continue`, a loop that uses them more than once will be hard to read. But don't replace them with something worse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do it.

Your manipulation of 'i' in the for loop is questionable already. Trying to mess with the iterator in a foreach-loop would be downright dirty. If it compiles at all.

I would write your example with a `break` or as:

```
bool myCondition=false;
for(int i=0;i<5 && !myCondition;i++)
{
   ....
}
```

In a foreach loop, when you're done before the entire sequence is complete, just call `break`

Comment: @Harikrishna: The difference between break and goto is that usually there are cleaner ways of expressing the same control flow than using goto; break is a natural way of expressing a reasonably common control flow.

Comment: Reluctantly, because of the limitations of `break`, we use `goto` to get out of nested loops.

Comment: That's where the labeled break in Java is occasionally useful. Mind you, I find that refactoring the loops into separate methods often leads to cleaner code at that point anyway.

Comment: @Jon, agreed. A concrete example could probably be solved even better with LINQ. But it is a 'problem' with many gradations.

Answer (score 10):

You should use what's in the language. There's no need to avoid `break` - just use it. Or to put it another way, "I don't want to use `break`" is not a good enough justification: if you think you've got a really good *reason* not to use it, then you should explain that reason. Don't hobble yourself by pretending perfectly reasonable features don't exist, and coming up with convoluted schemes to avoid them.

Comment: Would you apply this same reasoning to `goto`?  Or would you turn it around for `goto` and say that you better have a good reason *to* use before it's acceptable?

Comment: @tvanfosson: If you're in a situation where `goto` provides the cleanest way to express yourself (which is *very occasionally* the case in a switch statement) then yes, I'd use the same reasoning. It's considerably rarer than `break` though.

Comment: goto is also a keyword that is there for a reason. If you have the perfect candidate for 'goto' in your code, why not use it?

Comment: @Axarydax - I don't think anyone disagrees there, just that the "perfect candidate" is very, very rare.

Comment: @Jon - I'd say there's a presumption of guilt for a `goto` rather than a presumption of innocence.  I can't really think of any situations where I'd prefer it over another mechanism except as a glorified `break` -- transferring control from the innermost loop of several nested loops to the statement following the looping constructs.  Even the switch case I'd prefer to refactor to call a method rather than transfer to a block via `goto`.

Comment: @Jon -- or more plainly, I've always got a good reason **not** to use a goto, what I need is a **better** reason to use it than not.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably going to get me downvoted...  but you should use the break keyword.

Failing that:

```
foreach(var foo in bar)
{
  if(condition)
  {
    //perform normal loop code
    //set condition if required.
  }
  //otherwise do nothing - the loop will iterate all the way to the end without 
  //doing anything.
}
```

You could be more expressive and use `if(condition){ /*blah*/}else { continue; }` inside the loop - but either way it does the same thing.

You can't do much else to break out of a for each other than:

- Use `break`
- Throw an Exception

Answer (score 2):

In general, the 'pattern' you describe here is a code smell. It is NOT a good idea to change the index variable in a for-loop. It can result in unreadable, hard-to-maintain code, especially if the loop grows large.

That being said, *why* would you not want to use the `break` keyword. It is meant for this purpose, and whatever downside it has (in your opinion) is still a far better solution than the one you describe here.

Last, I see no way to do the same thing using a `foreach` loop in a sensible way.

Answer (score 1):

Not using break in your for(;;) loop is a serious stylistic mistake.  But you'll get away with it.  But not when you use foreach, you *have* to use the break keyword.

Pay attention to the title of this [blog post](http://www.sundog.net/sunblog/posts/code-as-if-the-next-guy-to-maintain-your-code-is-a-homicidal-maniac-who-kno/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, thats why there is this comand "break". I have no reasons why shouldnt you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should absolutely be:

```
bool myCondition = false;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   // do stuff
   if(myCondition)
      break;
}
```

Not only are you using the commands (i.e. tools) provided by the language, but you are keeping the code very readable, and maintainable. The `break` command is fundamental to the language.

Trying to come up with some reason not to use `break` is like doing math *on* a calculator -- literally, turn the calculator over, get a silver paint marker, and do some math. You are crippling yourself by not using the tools in front of you.